# Is There a Way to Make a Repeated GIF Background That Randomly Changes GIF After Each Loop in HTML?

Tags: html, image, background, background-image

I'm really new to HTML and I'm trying to make a small website for my art.

I was wondering if it's possible to have my background choose randomly from a set of GIFs for each tile and after one loop to randomly select another GIF. I'm specifically trying to have a unique GIF for each tile and wasn't sure how to even go about doing this since I only know how to make one GIF repeat across the entire background.

In case what I'm asking doesn't make sense, I'm attempting to have the background of my website look like the floor of an arcade. I didn't want to be the same few squiggles and shapes in a repeated pattern and thought it would be cool if instead each one changed into a separate squiggle/shape after a few seconds.

Thank you if you can help and sorry if this sounds at all silly or anything.

I tried looking into this elsewhere and just couldn't find anything I understood, so I thought to ask here.

Comment: Well yes, this is possible by means of [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and programming logic. Are you ready for getting into that? With HTML or even CSS only this is not possible. Btw, you should use real video formats for animations, not GIF, which is an outdated format and very heavy on the browser.

Comment: @Andy Sure, I'd be willing to give it a shot. I haven't touched Javascript since I took a single programming class in high school, but if you know of a tutorial of some kind that can help me with what I'm trying to do and how to use it alongside HTML, that'd be very cool :) Again, I'm doing super early beginner stuff so I'd need something to hold my hand a lot of the way through it.